# Where should I store API keys for my NodeJS app deployed with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, api-key

I've built an application with NodeJS that uses several third-party paid services, accessed through their API.

As per best practices, I haven't committed the file containing these API keys to my repository. However I'm at the point now where I want to deploy with Elastic Beanstalk but it seems there's no way for me to deploy directly from my repo without committing my keys.

What is the proper/best approach for deploying an app with the necessary keys without risking their security by committing them to an insecure repo?

Answer (score 1):

Many third party hosting services (like AWS, Heroku, Openshift, etc.) allow you to set environment variables for your application.  Generally setting API keys as environment variables is the best practice with regards to security, as it avoids them being stored locally, or in version history.

As to how to set them, that will be service dependent.

Edit: Amazon offers a page here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html

The short answer is to use:

```
eb setenv key=value
```